# Unable to click the rating image via capybara using selenium-cucumber

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, cucumber, capybara

This is the below html code. When the mouse hovered over the star images the image source turn to star-on.png. If you see the below code it means i gave two star rating.

```
<div id="user_rating" class="rating" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px;">
<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-on.png" alt="1" title="">&nbsp;
<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-on.png" alt="2" title="">&nbsp;
<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="3" title="">&nbsp;
<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="4" title="">&nbsp;
<img src="/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png" alt="5" title="">
<input type="hidden" name="score"></div>
```

I tried the following code in the cucumber using the img src, all and  values but I am not able to click the rating images

**img_src passed as "/assets/jquery.raty/star-off.png"**

```
Then /^I click on the image with src "([^\"]*)"$/ do |img_src|
   find("img[src=\'#{img_src}\']", match: :prefer_exact).click
end
```

**alt_text is passed as "3"**

```
Then /^I click on the image with alt "([^\"]*)"$/ do |alt_text|
  page.execute_script %Q[jQuery("img[alt=\'{alt_text}\']").first().mouseenter();]
  page.execute_script %Q[jQuery("img[alt=\'#{alt_text}\']").first().click();]
end
```

**selector = proper xpath is passed**

```
And /^I click by xpath "([^\"]*)"$/ do |selector|
  find(:xpath, selector, visible: true, match: :first).click
end
```

Can some one let me know a proper selenium command to click the rating

Comment: How do know it is not clicked? Do you handle the clicks in javascript? Could you post your scenario, so that we can your calls?

Comment: I Ran the feature file and the feature got failed in the next step as the rating is not given the page is not getting submitted. Yes Javascript is used to Initialize the rating

Comment: Could you post the scenario from the feature file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to click on a specific star you'd need to do

```
find("#user_rating img[alt='2']").hover.click # select star 2
```

So in a cucumber step that would be something like

```
Then /^I rate ([^ ]+) with (\d) stars$/ do |id, stars|
  find("##{id} img[alt='#{stars}']").hover.click
end
```

and be called as

```
Then I rate user_rating with 4 stars
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to escape the single quotes in your first two solutions: \' => '. Does that work?

The javascript in your second solution should be changed:

```
page.execute_script %Q[jQuery("img[alt=\'#{alt_text}\']").first().trigger('click');]
```